# MS Access 2016 vba: Empty value passed from form field (text box)

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016, ms-access-forms

I'm having a strange situation:

I have a simple form with 2 text boxes. 
The second one has the vba code triggered after being updated.
For example: typing value to the first field, ENTER, typing value into the second field, ENTER and the code starts.

The code, initially, takes the values from the text boxes and assign them to the string variables (pre declared as strings), like:

```
test1 = Me.frmSSN.Value
```

The problem is, the test1 variable seems to be empty after the line above.
It seems to happen only when I type, for example this string:

> 073QB8KJ2D00A4X

It works fine, when entering CNB0K2W5JK
The tool is a simple serial number comparison.

Just for test, I've entered this line into the code:

```
aaa="073QB8KJ2D00A4X"
```

When running in the step-by-step mode and hovering mouse over the "aaa" I'm getting: aaa= and then nothing. 
Not even single "" like aaa="" or so. Just aaa=

After retrying multiple things - I believe it's about the value I enter:

> 073QB8KJ2D00A4X

Could be, that for access/vba it's some control string or so?

I'm just dumb now...

Thanks in advance for any help

Marek

p.s. Source fields are plain text boxes. And here's the code:

Dim user As String
Dim 1stSN As String
Dim 2ndSN As String
1stSN = Me.frmSSN.Value
2ndSN = Me.frmHPSN.Value

Then the values are being used as a part of SQL query. The problem is - in this situation - query doesn't work, as the sql string looks like:

"Select * From sbo_SerialSource where SN like " and nothing after "like".
Debug shows the correct value (with serial number), but query fails with "syntax error" message. Seems like there are some strange "control characters" are being created/added.

That's it.
And I have to use the serial numbers as these "strange ones", because that's how they come from the vendor.

Comment: Can you show all the code, including the trigger event.

Comment: Yes, you have found a weird scenario. Actually, 'aaa' does contain the expected value! I was testing and kept seeing where aaa appeared empty, but when I did 'Len(aaa)' it returned 15! Then doing a For i = 1 to Len(aaa)          Debug.Print i & vbTab & Mid(aaa, i, 1) & vbTab & Asc(Mid(aaa, i, 1))
    Next i
It shows all of the characters! Now we just need to figure out how to display it...

Comment: have you tried the `.text` value?

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue. Provide your code.

Comment: @June7 if you create a Sub with only the following two lines: 
    aaa = "073QB8KJ2D00A4X"
    Debug.Print "aaa = " & aaa
   You will see the Debug shows the value. However if you place your cursor over 'aaa' after it is initialized, then it appears empty.

Comment: I already did that as an attempt to replicate issue. I set breakpoint and aaa is not empty in the popup tip. However, I am using Access2010. Is something different for 2016?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn, please examine the aaa in the watch window. what is its type?

Comment: I dimmed it as String before testing

Comment: @Nathan_Sav: yes and I've got the run-time error 2185: You can't reference the property or method for a control, unles the control has has the focus.

Comment: OK, I've narrowed the problem down to ...."KJ" in the serial number. aa = "KJ" gives the same issue. The aa appears to be empty. Is it a kind of a control character or what?

Comment: Tested "KJ" in various locations in string, including the string posted in question. Still cannot replicate the issue. Post the full SQL statement. Are you using apostrophe delimiters for the text parameter?

Comment: I can replicate this bug on win10_x64 with office 2013/2016, no value on hover If string contains 'KJ' . The value can be used as usual, except in a stored query with the forms textbox as criteria, but you can work around with a parameter-query. Did someone report this to mircosoft?